# Using difference/clip tools in QGIS without it creating blank layer?

Tags: qgis, clip

I am using QGIS in an effort to find addresses without municipal water in arkansas.  I have a polygon layer of Arkansas public water systems as well as a point layer of arkansas residencies.  I believe I need to use the difference tool to be able to cut out all of the residencies that are overlapping with the public water systems, but everytime I try that, it just creates a blank shapefile layer. How should I go about cutting the layers?

Comment: Can you add the extent of the layers, as reported by Rightclick, Properties, Metadata tab, Properties section? Both Layers **MUST** have the same CRS.

Answer (score 1):

The difference tool is not really appropriate here. As Andre suggested, first check that both layers have the same CRS. You could use the Spatial Query plugin to select those addresses which intersect the water systems layer, then reverse the selection. This will give you only the addresses outside the water systems layer. You can then save the selected points in a new layer if you need to.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of using the spatial query, thanks so much!